# Update JavaFx grid size

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

how do I change my JavaFx Grid? I want to be able to add/remove rows/columns but I am not sure how to do this.

```
<GridPane fx:id="gameGrid" gridLinesVisible="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0">
          <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="-Infinity" percentWidth="33.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="-Infinity" percentWidth="33.0" />
              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="-Infinity" percentWidth="33.0" />
          </columnConstraints>
          <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" percentHeight="33.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" percentHeight="33.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" percentHeight="33.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
          </rowConstraints>
           <children>
              <ImageView fitHeight="90.0" fitWidth="90.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                 <image>
                    <Image url="@X.png" />
                 </image>
              </ImageView>
           </children>
        </GridPane>
```

Can I change it from my controller in this function?

```
public void updateGrid(int cols, int rows){
    gameGrid.getRowConstraints().removeAll();
    gameGrid.getColumnConstraints().removeAll();
    gameGrid.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(cols));
    gameGrid.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(rows));
}
```

So I've tried adding new rows/columns. Except the sizing I applied in Scenebuilder will be distorted and my old rows/columns don't get removed. How would I remove the old and replace them, keeping the correct sizing properties?

I've tried this but it does not do anything for me except add 1 new row/column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to update the constraints, not the children, you should fill simply update the `rowConstraints` and `columnConstraints` the way you'd update any other list (i.e. using `clear` and `add`):

```
public void updateGrid(int cols, int rows) {
    List<RowConstraints> rowList = gameGrid.getRowConstraints();
    rowList.clear();
    if (rows > 0) {
        RowConstraints rowConstraints = new RowConstraints();
        rowConstraints.setPercentHeight(100d / rows);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            rowList.add(rowConstraints);
        }
    }

    List<ColumnConstraints> columnList = gameGrid.getColumnConstraints();
    columnList.clear();
    if (cols > 0) {
        ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
        columnConstraints.setPercentWidth(100d / cols);
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            columnList.add(columnConstraints);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** `removeAll` doesn't do what you expect it to do: It removes all the elements you pass as the varargs parameter to the list. You don't pass any elements in your code and the list is not modified by the method call.